# squid and additional SSL_ports

Tags: ssl, port, squid

I have to use a portal that uses AJAX requests not only to the base SSL port (443) of the server, there are also a SSL request to the 8443 port. 
My squid denies these request due to the rule:
 http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

Adding the 8443 port to the SSL_ports solves the problem, but I am not sure this is a security constraint. Is it?
I am in contact with the operator of the site. Should I try to force them to think about another solution? What are the reasons to change their site behavior?

Regards 
Rainer

Answer (score 0):

> What are the reasons to change their site behavior?

The main reason is that they likely want their site to be reachable.

It is not uncommon today that firewalls (and not only proxies) restrict access to only port 80 and 443 which means that valued customers could have problems to properly interact with their site. This can mean loss of business or additional costs related to supporting unhappy customers.